# What should I be looking for in applications to avoid awoxers in Eve?

Tags: eve-online

Recently we had an awoxer (someone who shoots his corp mates) join our corporation and cause around 500 million isk in damages. I would like to avoid this in the future by better screening future applicants to avoid being awoxed.

My corporation currently only resides in hi-sec and we do some small lo-sec pvp roams. Currently for screening we don't allow trial accounts and we check to see if a player has killed any fellow corp mates as well as talking to the person to see if they have a good attitude.

What else should we be looking for in applicants to avoid getting awoxers?

Comment: You build a better application you will just find a better lier not sure we can answer this question.

Comment: @Ramhound No doubt there will always be the potential for someone to be able to get past the application process no matter what the restrictions. However, it should be sufficiently difficult that most awoxers would be deterred or found out. I have spoken to someone who has been in a Corporation of over 150 guys who haven't had an awoxer in over 2 years - so they must be doing something right.

Comment: You could try looking up the applicants previous corp history, and ask CEO of the corps what the applicant was like, if he left on bad terms etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can require a full API and run the API through [this](http://ridetheclown.com/eveapi/audit.php) website. Look for anything that makes it look like the character is an alt of another character (suspicious money transfers, trades for free). If you find any such signs, check the connected character and see if there is any history.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at their killboard history in zkillboard. You can also look at the relative age/knowledge of the character. Give a detailed interview, use terminology that people might not know if they are trying to play off as new.

Really though, keeping your forces safe is like locking your car. You cannot prevent someone who is determined, but you can cause your corp to be less attractive then the next one. Many of these AWOXers are opportunists. Don't take them out with your bling for at least the first month or so. Don't brag about what kinds of things you field, or your isk/hour.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want to point out there is no way to avoid awoxing entirely, but there are several ways do reduce risk.

[Do your homework]
Doing your research on EVE Who, checking the API and killboards is the obvious first step.

[Spy]
You could pose as a bad guy yourself, especially if you have an alt that did some ganking or awoxing in the past. 
Use a locator agent to track your new potential recruit and 'accidently' run into him and find an angle to start a conversation.
If he thinks you are evil he's probably someone you want in your mining fleet. If he starts bragging about his last awox, simply don't accept him. It may sound like a long shot, but some awoxxers have an ego the size of Antartica and love to talk.

[Hire an specialist]
Alternatively you could hire an information broker. I have hired The Shadow Broker @ EVE Intel Corp a couple of times with great results. He's expensive but 'so is your mining fleet' he would tell you.

[Restructure]
Lastly you could restructure your corporation. Create an asset-rich holding corp that only your inner circle has access to and a secondary corp for the other members. (ideal for alliances)